# How to implement Push notification in xcode 7.3

Tags: firebase, apple-push-notifications, cocoapods, xcode7.3, swift2

I want to implement older Firebase notification any link for older SDKs and old Pod version
I am using Xcode 7.3 and I want to implement firebase push notification but
due to latest pod I can't run project and comes error in FIRMessagingDelegate and FIRInstanceID I install both pod but method is not working.

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
    let pushNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(pushNotificationSettings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    print("DEVICE TOKEN = \(deviceToken)")
}
func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    print(error)
}
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    print(userInfo)
}
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}


func application(_application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                   fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                         withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler()
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")

    // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
    // Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
}
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question. What are you trying to accomplish? What did you do? What is the expected result? Which errors do you get ("i cant run project" is no error description)

Comment: hi i am trying to implement push notification in xcode 7.3 when i install pod some framework is not import like UserNotifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding pod Version in change log  and install pod 
pod 'Firebase', '~> 3.10'
pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '~> 1.0’
and after install pod 
letest pod dose't suppot userNotifications Framwork